# Matlab, on the quest to find a simple way to control the output of a function

Tags: matlab

I have already asked a similar question here, I will try this time to be a lot more elaborate in consideration that what puzzles me the most about Matlab still is how to handle/control output as in plotting/listing.

I have the following function

```
function e = calcEulerSum2(n)


for i=1:n                               % step size still one, although left blank
   e = 1;
   e = e + sum(1./factorial(1:n));      % computes a vector of length n and takes 
end                                     % the factorial of its entries, then piecewise division
end
```

To approximate e using the Taylor Summation method. I am now asked to compute the absolute error using

```
abserror(n):=abs(calcEulerSum2(n)-exp(1))
```

for values of `n= 10^0,10^1,...,10^16`.

My idea was to make the above function sensitive for vector input (if you call it like that, I have read vectorization on here as well). I thought this would be the best thing I could do, because I obviously want to evaluate the above function for a couple of values of `n` and then maybe plot the result in a graph to see the results.

However, I believe that my understanding of MATLAB is too rudimentary as of now to find a simple solution to that problem.

**Additional**: With the help of this website I already managed to solve a similar problem, using a recursive definition of e to get a vector output for each successful iteration using:

```
function e = calcEulerSum3(n)

for i = n                       % here the idea is to let n be a continuous vector

    e(1)=1;                     % base case
    e(i+1)=e(i)+1/factorial(i); % recursive definition to approx e

end
```

This function now understands vector input, but only if the vector is what I would call continuous on the integer line, for example `n'=[ 1 2 3 4 5 ]` and so on to make the recursive iteration through a vector work. This time however, my vector `n` as above would destroy this concept.

**Question(s)**:

- Are there simple ways to handle the above output `abserror(n)` ?, because I have a feeling that I am overachieving by trying to vectorize my functions

**Update**: As suggested by @vish the following function does a much better job for my purpose:

```
function e = calcEulerSum2(n) %Updated 


for i=1:n                            % step size still one, although left blank
   e = 1;
   e = e + cumsum(1./factorial(1:n));      % computes a vector of length n and takes 
end                                     % the factorial of its entries, then piecewise division
end
```

the output of this program for `n=3` would be

> > calcEulerSum2(3)

ans =

```
2.0000    2.5000    2.6667
```

This is great and indeed what I am looking for, but lets say I want to plot the absolute error now for several values of n, for the sake of the argument I will choose smaller values (because I understand that 10^16! is really blunt to input), but still many. So if I decide I want to print out the absolute error `abserror(n)` for the following values of n

```
n = [1 4 9 11 17 18 19 22 27 29 31 33 ]
```

how would I do that?

Comment: Do you really want to take the the factorial of `1e16` in here?

Comment: @RobertP, good call, this is an assignment I am given for a numerical methods course, I copied the numbers from my paper. If I compute the above function by hand in matlab (the recursive defined one) I can see after 5 steps already that the number gets seemingly close to what we call e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you are computing what you think you are computing.

The for loop is totally not needed since you keep overwriting e at every iteration and you only return the last one.

```
factorial(1:3) == [1,2,6]
```

then you sum the reciprocals.

The first iteration of the loop factorial(1:1) goes nowhere.

Try

```
cumsum(1./factorial(1:7))
```

l think that's what you wanted

Edit: , factorial(10^5) is too big to be meaningful,  i think going from 1 to n=16 will give you good enough results. (not 10^16)

---

2nd edit

run this

```
N=0:16;
res = exp(1) - cumsum(1./factorial(N))
```

see what happens

you can also plot it on a log scale.

```
semilogy(res)
```

Comment: If you bother to format some code, and capitalize the first letter in sentences ++ you might just get a +1 =)

Comment: @vish, thanks a lot for your answer. I appreciate it. You are right, the cumsum looks very promising, I have read about it but I should have taken in consideration to use it for this problem. However, this input does not seem to be sensitive for an input if I define my vector to be n=1:16 and use that as an input. In my assignment, although I confess it seems useless, I am supposed to enter in 17 values for n, am I supposed to enter them in all by hand?  How would I plot that?

Comment: @vish, I found a way to make use of your suggestion, not as a plot but as a list which will completely do for my problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @RobertP. - You got it.

Comment: @Spaced. 

again , the loop is superfluous, try my last bit of code. see the result. 1:17 would also work or 1:2:33